# mkdir and copy functions.. owned by account?

Tags: php

How can I make it so that when a directory and an image is copied to my server, it is owned by the user account and not by PHP?

Does PHP chown work?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php, this might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`chown` does work provided php has permissions to run it, and permission to chown the file.

You have 2 options. You could change the user running PHP, or set up an `access control list` so everyone can access the folder regardless of ownership.

To change the user running PHP, you will need to edit `httpd.conf` for apache, or `www.conf` for php-fpm. If you're using PHP another way, you may need to manually investigate how to change it. This will affect everything that is run by PHP so it's important to `chown/chmod` them too.

httpd.conf

```
User username;
Group group;
```

www.conf for php-fpm

```
listen.owner = username;
listen.group = group;
```

For an access control list, you can make it so every file placed in a folder is automatically accessible by people who aren't owners or in the right group. This has the added benefit of not caring about where the files came from so the permissions will be right if you also manually upload them or copy them there.

```
[user@host ~]$ setfacl -RLdm o::rwx /path/to/folder
```